# node-gyp errors on "Cannot find module" on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, node-gyp

I'm trying to build Atom. When I run `npm install`,  I get an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js'
```

I'm on Windows. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update 2020:** there are reports in the comments that this method (which definitely worked in 2014) does not work anymore. Please make a backup of this folder before deleting anything.

---

This means that somehow, the `node-gyp` module has been corrupted, uninstalled, or otherwise screwed up. This is can be fixed in two easy steps(tm):

1. Nuke `node-gyp` from orbit just in case of corruption or something. Open PowerShell as an administrator, `cd` to the install directory of Node (probably either `C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` or `C:\Program Files\nodejs`). Now `cd .\node_modules\npm\node_modules` and `rm -r node-gyp`.
2. Reinstall `node-gyp`. To do this, just run `npm install`.

Comment: For ionic framework issue, i removed node-gyp `npm remove node-gyp` then ran `npm install`.  fixed, thanks

Comment: @Stanly ask a new question :-)

Comment: Does not work, makes npm end up in a perpetual broken state where no commands work anymore with an even more persistent `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` error code.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Same for me

Comment: LoL - could ya move that "UPDATE" to the top of this answer?  Would have been nice to read that first!

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to solve (i faced issue after update my node)

1 . check your node where it is install

2 . check where your node-gyp path comes from

step:1 (cmd or shell)

```
which node
```

output

```
/c/Program Files/nodejs/node
```

Tips: after i update my node-gyp path is changed ,now easy to track we already got path

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node_gyp.js
```

now we are going to set right path

step:2

```
npm config list
```

now you can see node-gyp path

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.12.0 node/v12.9.0 win32 ia32"

; userconfig C:\Users\balaji\.npmrc
init-author-name = "Balaji"
init-license = "MIT"
msvs_version = "2017"
node_gyp = "C:\\Users\\balaji\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
python = "C:\\Users\\balaji\\.windows-build-tools\\python27/python.exe"

; globalconfig C:\Users\balaji\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\balaji\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = G:\all clients project\2020\anware
; HOME = C:\Users\balaji
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

Now time to change right path, Must Run in power shell

```
npm config set node_gyp /path/to/executable/node_gyp
```

Tips if all configuration right simply delete node_modules folder then run npm install in your node path