# npm install that requires node-gyp fails on Windows

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

I have a NPM project that uses `bufferutils` and `utf-8-validate`, both requiring node-gyp to install them. When I do `npm install`, I get following error:

```
> bufferutil@1.2.1 install C:\Users\Marek\WEB\moje-skoly\web-app\node_modules\bufferutil                       
> node-gyp rebuild                                                                                             


C:\Users\Marek\WEB\moje-skoly\web-app\node_modules\bufferutil {git}{hg}                                        
{lamb} if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-g
yp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )                        
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.    
  bufferutil.cc                                                                                                
C:\Users\Marek\.node-gyp\5.1.1\include\node\v8.h(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': 
 No such file or directory [C:\Users\Marek\WEB\moje-skoly\web-app\node_modules\bufferutil\build\bufferutil.vcx 
proj]                                                                                                          
gyp ERR! build error                                                                                           
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1           
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Marek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nod
e-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)                                                                                     
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)                                                                
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)                                                      
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)                   
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586                                                                          
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Marek\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\
npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"                                                       
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Marek\WEB\moje-skoly\web-app\node_modules\bufferutil                                     
gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.1                                                                                        
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1                                                                                    
gyp ERR! not ok                                                                                                
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`                                 
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1
```

Previously it failed because of Python 2.7 not installed, now it is this. It's causing me headaches. What should I do about this?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The answer below stands for a manual installation, but there is a much simpler way : the automatic install.

Open Powershell as admin and run `npm install -g windows-build-tools`.

The install takes time but it worked like a charm for me !

Comment: **Warning** This method force rebooted my machine and I had unsaved files, which I lost. Windows 8.1 edit: omg thankyou vscode it was still there when I opened the folder.

Comment: If the installation process got stuck somewhere, use the version 4.0.0 instead `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools@4.0.0`. Credit goes to: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools/issues/152#issuecomment-443785591

Answer (score 24):

I found this [brilliant solution](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/802) on GitHub:

1. Your OS MUST be Windows
2. Check that python is in your path by writting `python --version` in the console. If not then
3. Download python 2.7 (I recommend [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/python2) (`choco install python2 -y`)) and add `python.exe` to your PATH variable.
4. Aren't you on Windows 7? Skip 5 and 6.
5. [Check that you have .NET 4.5.1+ installed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If not then
6. [Download and install .NET 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773) (.NET 4.5.2 will also work just fine)
7. Download [Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools 2015 Technical Preview](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159)
8. Use custom install. Install the Windows 8.1 SDK if you haven't already. Apparently, it doesn't matter what OS you're on. You just need the Windows 8.1 SDK.
9. Set the npm config variable msvs_version to 2015: `npm config -g set msvs_version 2015`
10. Do `npm i` in what-ever project with node-gyp as a dependency without seeing weird error messages

My nightmares are gone!

Comment: this is why windows user are not happy with node-gyp rebuild  . Brilliant solution itself is too Big . Unhappy with the nodegyp Crap

Comment: Build tools can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

Comment: For me (windows 10 node 6.2.0), `npm config -g set msvs_version 2013` worked when `2015` and `2012` didn't (I installed VS 2013, 2012, and 2015)

Answer (score 4):

I couldn't find my solution anywhere else, so thought I'd share.

Running node v10.16.3 on Windows 10

Install windows-build-tools -

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Set the python path explicitly in C:\Users[your username].npmrc - In my case, this is like so:

```
python=c:\users\akeel\.windows-build-tools\python27\python
```

Comment: Also make sure the `msbuild_path` variable is setup properly in your `.npmrc`! I spent literally days debugging a project that wouldn't build properly only to find out that my `msbuild_path` was pointing to the wrong version of msbuild

Answer (score 2):

**Started Working For Me**

Nothing work for me (installed msvs_version 2017,2015)

Noticed

node-gyp error comes from  python path and msvsc path

```
npm config list
```

Output (set correct installed path and msvs)

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.12.0 node/v12.9.0 win32 ia32"

; userconfig C:\Users\balaji\.npmrc
init-author-name = "Balaji"
init-license = "MIT"
msvs_version = "2017"
node_gyp = "C:\\Users\\balaji\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js"
python = "C:\\Users\\balaji\\.windows-build-tools\\python27/python.exe"

; globalconfig C:\Users\balaji\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Users\\balaji\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = G:\all clients project\2020\anware
; HOME = C:\Users\balaji
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

To Set globaly(eg)

```
npm config -g set msvs_version 2015
```

To Set localy (eg)

```
npm config  set msvs_version 2015
```

Path correction

```
 npm config set python /path/to/executable/python
```

for those who Not installed yet(it install  msvsc and python)

```
npm install -g windows-build-tools
```

after install check above givn tips such as path and version everything

happy coding....

detail info updated
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68630586/11624647

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when updating from an older version of node to node v12. There was a particular issue with bcrypt library. I just uninstalled v12 and installed v10 and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/03/27/node-gyp-windows/

I had to install Windows Build Tools 2015 and then set Node to use it.

Here are the commands I've used:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2015
npm config set msvs_version 2015 –global
```

Answer (score -3):

Using WSL works for me (windows 10 users only)

those who dont know what WSL is simply Linux command shell in windows

just follow this guide to install WSL https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WSL 
and install nodejs and npm my using commands

`sudo apt-get install nodejs npm -y`

Comment: It would be nice if you'd put up a solution for windows (without the WSL compatibility layer)