# Getting Error when I am doing npm install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-gyp

I am getting a gyp error when I am executing `npm install` in my project

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\bakhil\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v10.15.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "clean" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\bakhil\source\repos\BOSS.Web\node_modules\@newrelic\native-metrics
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Failed to execute native-metrics install: No pre-built artifacts for your OS/architecture.

I am also getting error when it is executing node-gyp rebuild

```
> mmmagic@0.5.2 install C:\Users\bakhil\source\repos\BOSS.Web\node_modules\mmmagic
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\bakhil\source\repos\BOSS.Web\node_modules\mmmagic>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 514, in gyp_main
    options.duplicate_basename_check)
  File "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1916, in CalculateVariables
    generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
  File "C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 434, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
    versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
KeyError: '2019'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (C:\Users\bakhil\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v10.15.1\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:345:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\bakhil\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v10.15.1\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\bakhil\source\repos\BOSS.Web\node_modules\mmmagic
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mmmagic@0.5.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mmmagic@0.5.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried a lot of solutions none work.

node version is 10.15.1

python version is 2.7.17

nvm running version is 1.1.7

Please help me to resolve this error. I am new to react-js

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install that requires node-gyp fails on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293117/npm-install-that-requires-node-gyp-fails-on-windows)

Comment: I will try once @Fcmam5

Comment: npm ERR! mmmagic@0.5.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
still I am getting this error @Fcmam5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure npm to find your python version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56931338/10849438)

Comment: @MwamiTovi, Yeah I tried that solution too, but not working

Answer (score 2):

Per [newrelic](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/native-metrics-fails-installing-on-mac-os/82520), you can simply install newrelic with no optional dependencies.

`npm install newrelic --no-optional`