# node-gyp keeps throwing this error every time i run npm install on my project

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Fragile\Desktop\omnipublish-for-testing\OPV5\OMNIPUBLISH\srcDispatch\node_modules\iltorb
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! info install installing standalone, skipping download.
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.4.2 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\Fragile\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack   File "", line 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack                       ^
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:397:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1067:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Fragile\Desktop\omnipublish-for-testing\OPV5\OMNIPUBLISH\srcDispatch\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Fragile\Desktop\omnipublish-for-testing\OPV5\OMNIPUBLISH\srcDispatch\node_modules\iltorb
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.4.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Fragile\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-01T02_58_14_892Z-debug.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install that requires node-gyp fails on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293117/npm-install-that-requires-node-gyp-fails-on-windows)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.